Google Auth - Detect if will throw 403 disallowed_useragent
Every other question I've read is asking how to bypass or workaround Google's policy that prevents access from embedded web views; I want to comply but I want to help my users.
I have a web based application (no native app involved) which redirects to Google Auth and back to the website - I don't want to use the JavaScript solution for various reasons, and generally this approach works really well.
I recently got a support request from a user who had received the disallowed_useragent error.  After hours of research I eventually discovered they had been sent a link to my app in Facebook Messenger, clicked it and tried to login within the messengers webview; which obviously failed.
I would like to display users in this position a message, telling them to try a real browser - but how can I detect the user agent is on Google's disallow list?
Thanks.

The error message the users are getting is coming from Googles Authorization server before it hits your application. Due to that there is probably no way that you can catch it.
This is a common issue due to the fact that Facebook seems to think that we want to view links in their browser rather than being secure and opening it in the system browser.

Absolutely Facebooks fault!!  But the flow is My_Page (that's the link the user has) > Google > Error; so if I has a list of disallowed urls; I could prevent the redirect to Google

the issue isnt the url the issue is where its being opened.  If the user was on their desktop and opened the url it would work.  The issue is the Facebook mobile app opens it in the Facebook internal browser as opposed to the browser on the mobile device.

having similar issue but from Tiktok embedded browser. even Google's official account there shows similar issue. So far only ChatGPT websites managed to make it work somehow.
